# Custom css applies only after page shrinks - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla2.5

Im using bootstrap with my custom css. the problem is that some styling from my custom css is applied only after i shrink my website with my browser, it adapts to smaller browser size and it applies my custom css, that same css dosent apply when website is in full size.

I uploaded a picture [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/botstrap.jpg/). you can see how text on the right side has styling. it happens also with menu items, but the wierd thing is that on some places it works normaly before and after shrinking the page, for example look at the picture at the background of login and contact forms, its my custom css gradient and it works in both cases, also the buttons work normally. can you help me somehow couse im confuzed how this works?

btw i dont know if it is important at all in this case but im using joomla 2.5 here

Comment: Can you share your HTML/CSS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only applying at a certain width, it means your custom CSS is within a media query.

I suspect you've got an error in your CSS somewhere.  I've had this myself, where I've inadvertently not closed a media query, which means that all of the CSS that flows beneath it in the stylesheet is only applied within those media query constraints.

Take a look through your CSS and make sure that all your media queries are closed correctly.  You can also validate your CSS file using the [W3 CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) - this should help identify where the bug is.

Also worth mentioning: when I'm working with Bootstrap I always use a completely separate stylesheet for my work (repeating classes to overwrite Bootstrap styles where needed).  If you extract all of your current styles into a separate file it will make debugging much easier, and may also remove the current issue you're having (where you styles appear to be embedded within a media query).

Comment: ok i will do it. but lets say if i want quicker solution would it work if i just add another .css file and start writing my custom css from there? couse im using a template that has few thousent lines of code, so i could just leave this css file as it is (fkors later run a W3C check to fix errors), and start writing my css in separete file (fkors without duplicating classes and ids)

Comment: That would absolutely be the best way to work!  It is far better to put all of your own CSS within a separate file than to try and edit Bootstrap.  Extracting your current styles into that same external stylesheet should also clear whatever media-query close issue you're facing at the moment, although you should still try and trace it down and fix it (you may see other issues otherwise).